# Convert JavaScript Array [a, b, c, d, e] into [a+b, b+c, c+d, d+e] dynamically

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

I have an array `[a, b, c, d, e, .....]` .

How can convert this like  `[a+b, b+c, c+d, d+e, ....]`

The reducer may be the best way to do this but how to store temp memory after calculation.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce

Please check this code

```js
function randomIntegerArray(length) {
  const random = Math.floor(
    Math.pow(10, length - 1) +
      Math.random() * (Math.pow(10, length) - Math.pow(10, length - 1) - 1),
  );
  return String(random).split('');
}
 const makeQuestions = (del, len) =>
    new Array(len)
      .fill(randomIntegerArray(del))
      .map((row, index) => {
      
      // row [a, b, c, d, e]
      // ans [a+b, b+c, c+d, d+e]
      let ans = [];
      
        return {
          question: row,
          answer: ans,
        };
      } );
      
      console.log(makeQuestions(5, 2));
```

Comment: What does `id: index + 1,
          question: row,
          desc: '',
          ref: '',
          options: '',
          answer: ans,` have to do with the question you are asking? Can you create a [mcve] ?

Comment: what is the second summand in the last iteration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some issues in your code:

- The `randomIntegerArray` function can only deal with lengths up to about 17, ... for greater values, it will keep producing zeroes beyond index 17. This is because of the precision limit that floating point has.
- The `randomIntegerArray` function does not do what its name says: it produces an array of strings, not of integers
- The `randomIntegerArray` function never produces a zero at index 0.
- The `randomIntegerArray` function cannot produce numbers greater than 9.
- Your code only generates *one* such random array, and then assigns that single array to several slots in your question array using `fill`. Although not clear from your question, it seems more likely you want to generate as many random arrays as you have "questions".

Here is how you could do the job, also addressing the above mentioned issues:

```js
const randomIntegerArray = (length, max=9) =>
    Array.from({length}, () => Math.floor(Math.random() * (max+1)));

const makeQuestions = (del, length) =>
    Array.from({length}, () => randomIntegerArray(del))
         .map((question, index) => ({
            question,
            anser: question.slice(0, -1)
                           .map((item, index) => item + question[index+1])
          }));
      
console.log(makeQuestions(5, 2));
```

Answer (score 1):

You have the original array `row` and you know the expected length and expected relation between two arrays, so you can achieve this by:

```js
function randomIntegerArray(length) {
  const random = Math.floor(
    Math.pow(10, length - 1) +
      Math.random() * (Math.pow(10, length) - Math.pow(10, length - 1) - 1),
  );
  return String(random).split('');
}
 const makeQuestions = (del, len) =>
    new Array(len)
      .fill(randomIntegerArray(del))
      .map((row, index) => {
      
      // row [a, b, c, d, e]
      // ans [a+b, b+c, c+d, d+e]
      let ans = row.slice(0,-1).map((item, index) => Number(item) + Number(row[index+1]));
      
        return {
          id: index + 1,
          question: row,
          desc: '',
          ref: '',
          options: '',
          answer: ans,
        };
      } );
      
      console.log(makeQuestions(5, 2));
```

Comment: Good solution with >>>    `row[index+1]`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) for this:

```js
const a = 1, b = 2, c = 3, d = 4, e = 5;

const result = [a, b, c, d, e].reduce((acc, el, i, sourceArr) => {
  if (i < sourceArr.length - 1) {
    acc.push(el + sourceArr[i + 1]);
  }
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

It uses the third (index) and fourth (source array) parameters of the `.reduce()` callback to filter out the last element and get the next element of the array to do the calculation.

In your example:

```js
function randomIntegerArray(length) {
  const random = Math.floor(
    Math.pow(10, length - 1) +
    Math.random() * (Math.pow(10, length) - Math.pow(10, length - 1) - 1),
  );
  return String(random).split('');
}
const makeQuestions = (del, len) =>
  new Array(len)
  .fill(randomIntegerArray(del))
  .map((row, index) => {

    // row [a, b, c, d, e]
    // ans [a+b, b+c, c+d, d+e]
    let ans = row.reduce((acc, el, i, sourceArr) => {
      if (i < sourceArr.length - 1) {
        acc.push(el + sourceArr[i + 1]);
      }
      return acc;
    }, []);

    return {
      question: row,
      answer: ans,
    };
  });

console.log(makeQuestions(5, 2));
```

Note that because `row` is an array of strings, it will concatenate the strings instead of calculate the addition. If you want to perform addition, you can either convert `arr` to an array of numbers, or change `el + sourceArr[i + 1]` to `+el + +sourceArr[i + 1]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Array#map`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_map.asp) combined with [`Array#slice`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_array.asp) like this:

```js
const a = 1, b = 2, c = 3, d = 4, e = 5;
const array = [a, b, c, d, e];
const result = array.map((v, index) => v + array[index+1]);

console.log(result.slice(0, array.length - 1));
```